# initialization from incompatible pointer type during array initialization

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

I have below code :

```
int main()
{
    int* abc[] ={
                    [3] = (&(int[3]){1,2,3}),
                    [2] = (&(int[2]){4,5})
                };
    printf("\n abc[3][1] = %d \n",abc[3][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to set up my array `abc` , so that specific indexes of the array point to a different array of integers.

Later, I would modify this to use macros so that array is initialized during pre-processing, hence such an approach.

Code works fine but I get a warning :

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

Is this because my array `abc` is declared to point to integer but it is actually pointing to array of integers?
How can I make this warning go away?

Comment: FormatTry......

Answer (score 3):

The types you're using in the compound literals are incorrect.

The elements of the array are `int *`, but when using `&`, the types of the compound literals are `int (*)[3]` and `int (*)[2]`.

It should be:

```
int* abc[] ={
                [3] = ((int[3]){1,2,3}),
                [2] = ((int[2]){4,5})
            };
```

Now `int[3]` and `int[2]` both decay to `int *`.

Comment: @dbush I took the liberty to edit in a clarification, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Lundin No problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to initialize `abc` without knowing the size of the subarrays?